# Altering table with 140+ columns is getting slower and slower

Tags: mysql, database-design

### Problem

Hi, I need a help with a database design. Right now, I have a database with 140 columns and 20M+ rows. The issue I face is following: I am adding new column approx. every week and every `alter` is slower than previous one. Last time, I was waiting for more than 20 minutes when adding 4 new columns.

This table was initially designed to have approx. 10 columns containing test configuration. We often export and filter those data (using Superset or sometimes Google Sheets). That is why every value has it's own column.

### Current stack

- MySQL 8.0.28; 2 vCPU; 2 GB RAM
- 4 indexes on most frequently used columns

### Possible options

- Changing the db schema to something more flexible in terms of altering the table
- Merging all "no often used for filtering" columns into single one containing a JSON with that config, that can be easily expanded in code, but bring some hard time with results visualisation

Can you help me, please?

---

### Additional information

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` (note: *some column names were anonymised*)

```
CREATE TABLE `table_a` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `uuid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_a` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_b` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_c` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_d` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'deprecated',
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_namerun_meta` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_namerequest_url` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  `col_namerun_by` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_name` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `col_a` (`col_a`),
  KEY `col_b` (`col_b`),
  KEY `col_c` (`col_c`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `col_d` (`col_d`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6424583 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

`SHOW TABLE STATUS`

```
Name    Engine  Version Row_format  Rows    Avg_row_length  Data_length Max_data_length Index_length    Data_free   Auto_increment  Create_time Update_time Check_time  Collation   Checksum    Create_options  Comment
results InnoDB  10  Dynamic 4441758 4535    20144193536 0   492568576   7340032 6424595 2023-07-26 09:02:44 2023-07-27 16:09:28 utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

`ALTER TABLE` (example)

```
ALTER TABLE `results`
CHANGE `test_a` `test_a` int NULL
```

```
ALTER TABLE `results`
DROP COLUMN `test_a`
```

### HW Utilisation

Last 7 days, 5 sec resolution
[image: util_1]
[image: util_2]
[image: util_3]
[image: util_4]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are continually adding more "columns", but not adding indexing to those columns, I recommend having a `JSON` column to put miscellany new stuff into.  (You could add a few JSON columns, each with some logical grouping.)

Consider moving most of your 140 columns into that JSON column(s), too.  But do not move the indexed columns into it.

Although JSON is designed for strings, it can hold INTs and FLOATs.  If desired, you could even group multiple strings and/or numbers into sub-structures (arrays/hashes).  The application would be responsible for understanding the substructure.

An old discussion of similar stuff:  [*Entity-Attribute-Value*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav)

Although MySQL 8.0 has a rather rich set of JSON access syntax, it is probably better to let the app unpack it.  PHP, for example, has `json_decode()` to promptly build a structure, include any substructures.

Comment: Thanks Rick, similar idea came to my mind. We also often filter using almost all values. Do you think we should move this search&filter into some app? This solution will also cannot be used together with Superset/Tableu/PowerBI, right?

Comment: @FN_ - Keep a few columns that are frequently searched on in columns with indexing; let the app further filter after reading the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative idea to Rick's is you can just store related groups of columns into their own tables that are related to the primary table via a foreign key. (The relationships should be one-to-one for each new table to the primary table.)

This would keep the data relational still should you want to eventually index some of those fields. It will also make consumption and manipulation easier since it won't need to be unpacked from JSON. And finally, it would obviously be supported by all consumers like reporting tools such as PowerBI just the same.

There's also no guessing on what the data types of the data is that's being stored. There may also be improved compression capabilities as well.

140+ columns is starting to become the size that's more than easily manageable for a single table, as you're seeing. But if you break everything up into related groups of columns in separate tables, then manageability becomes better, and you can just re-assemble everything in a View, should you need a single logical object to easily reference by consumers.

---

Aside from a software design perspective, from a hardware perspective, with the amount of data you have, you're probably on the edge of what your provisioned hardware can support with:

> 1 vCPU; 1 GB RAM

I would recommend 2 CPUs and 4 GB of RAM if possible. I wouldn't doubt your queries and operations are choking a little bit on your current hardware provisioning. Even just adding 1 GB of RAM more may make a measurable difference.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I am gonna consider that too. I have also added HW utilisation from last 7 days into question description. I will inspect increasing HW resources and doing some measurements first. Thank you

Comment: @FN_ Sure thing, np!